# How to access a JSON value with Vue.js without using v-for

Tags: json, vue.js, vue-component

I have the following json:

```
[{id: 3,
pais: "Chile",
fuso_atual: "-3",
fuso_api: "-7200",
dst: "1",
dst_start: "1476586800",
dst_end: "1487469599",
created_at: null,
updated_at: "2016-12-11 19:19:11"
}]
```

and I want to access this properties, but without using v-for or something like this, I want a simple access (in my html) like {{paises[0].pais}}, but when I try this, I get an error "Cannot read property 'pais' of undefined(…)"

My component:

```
var getTimeZone = {

    template: '#time-zone-list-template',

    data: function(){
        return {
            paises: []
        }
    },

    created: function(){
        this.getTimeZone2();
    },

    methods: {
        getTimeZone2: function(){
            this.$http.get('api/paises').then((response) => {
                this.paises = response.body;
            }); 
        } 
    }

};  

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    components: {
        'time-zone-list': getTimeZone
    }

});
```

My html:

```
<div id="app">
    <time-zone-list></time-zone-list>
</div>

<template id="time-zone-list-template">
    <div class="time-and-date-wrap">    
        {{ paises[0].pais }}
    </div>
</template>
```

Any idea?

edit: I can access {{ paises[0] }} with success, but not .pais

edit2: If I use v-for I can navigate in the inside properties

Thanks

Comment: Show your code. Here is a jsfiddle with array index access working: https://jsfiddle.net/sru0wuf3/

Comment: It's probabbly because data from server is not yet fetched, so you are getting that `paises` is not defined.Solution should be wrap everything in div and set directive `v-if="paises"`

Comment: @BelminBedak I tried this approach, but didn't work. I can access the array, but I can´t navigate in the inside properties

Comment: Okay, what if you change this `this.paises = response.body;` to this `this.paises = response.json();`

Comment: Or `response.data`

Comment: when I try with response.json() I get an object with undefined context, so I can´t navigate...

And response.data has the same behavior as response.body...

Comment: You're initializing the `paises` array as empty so on initial rendering of the page, there is no first element so the binding fails. Try initializing with a single object and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff Mercado's answer in the comment correctly describes why this fails.

You *could* add a computed property like this...

```
var getTimeZone = {

    template: '#time-zone-list-template',

    data: function(){
        return {
            paises: []
        }
    },

    created: function(){
        this.getTimeZone2();
    },

    computed: {
        elPrimerPais: function() {
            return this.paises.length > 0 ? this.paises[0].pais : '';
        }
    },

    methods: {
        getTimeZone2: function(){
            this.$http.get('api/paises').then((response) => {
                this.paises = response.body;
            }); 
        } 
    }

};
```

Then in your template you can do this..

```
<template id="time-zone-list-template">
    <div class="time-and-date-wrap">    
        {{ elPrimerPais }}
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks jessegavin! I have had a time to tested today and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution =>>> v-if="paises.length" this solved my problem =]

```
var getTimeZone = {

    template: '#time-zone-list-template',

    data: function(){
        return {
            paises: []
        }
    },

    created: function(){
        this.getTimeZone();
    },

    methods: {
        getTimeZone: function(){
            this.$http.get('api/paises').then((response) => {
                this.paises = response.body;
            }); 
        } 
    }

};
```

Then in my template

```
<template id="time-zone-list-template">
    <div class="time-and-date-wrap" v-if="paises.length">    
        {{ paises[0].pais }}
    </div>
</template>
```